# variable scope is getting duplicated

Tags: tensorflow

```
for i in range(3):
   with tf.variable_scope(str(i)):
       print tf.get_variable_scope()
```

When I print this I get first and 3rd variable scope as same. I expected it to be different variable scope as I am creating new variable scope each time

Answer (score 0):

They are different, but the point for them is the same. Maybe it just replaces previous point. There is no need to save different scopes because when the scope changes, you can only get the current scope.

But I didn't read through the code, not 100% sure.

```
for i in range(3):
    with tf.variable_scope(str(i)):
        print tf.get_variable_scope().name
```